# Prove that $\exists b\in \Bbb Z$ s.t $x^{ab}=x$.(A semi Direct Product question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

Suppose $K$ is a finite cyclic group, $H$ is an arbitrary group. Consider two homomorphisms $\phi_1, \phi_2: K \to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ s.t $\phi_1(K), \phi_2(K)$ are conjugate in $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.

Now let $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ s.t $\sigma \phi_1(K) \sigma^{-1}=\phi_2(K)$.

Since $K=\langle x\rangle$ is cyclic, $\sigma \phi_1(x) \sigma^{-1}=\phi_2(x)^a$ for some $a\in \Bbb Z$ then for any $k \in K$ ; $\sigma \phi_1(k) \sigma^{-1}=\phi_2(k)^a$.

> To prove that $\exists b\in \Bbb Z$ s.t $x^{ab}=x$.

I need this result to prove one problem from Dummit and Foote [Sec $5.5$ Question no $6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093104/isomorphism-of-semidirect-products-df). Please help, here in this post also I could not see the answer of my particular doubt.

Comment: This has nothing to do with $H$ or the $\phi_i$, this is simply a statement about finite cyclic groups.

Comment: Thank god, please help me. What property am I missing?