# Show that the map $\mathbb{Z}_n^*\to \mathbb{Z}_m^*$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m|n$. Show that the map $$f: \mathbb{Z}_n^*\to \mathbb{Z}_m^*$$ $$f({a \pmod n}) = (a \pmod m)$$ is surjective. I am not able to figure out any simple way to tackle this... Any hints?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487011/showing-that-a-homomorphism-between-groups-of-units-is-surjective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. Will prove by induction. We just have to show that the result holds when $n=mp$. Let $b \in \mathbb{Z}_m^*$.

If $b \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $(b,m)=1 \land (b,p)=1 \implies (b,n)=1 \implies b \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$. Now we have $f(b)=b$.

If $b \equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $m \not\equiv 0 \pmod p \implies b+m \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$. Therefore $(b+m,p)=1 \land (b+m,m)=1 \implies (b+m,n)=1 \implies b+m \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$. Now we have $f(b+m)=b$.

The inductive step is straightforward.

Comment: This is completely right in its substance. There's a slight imprecision in your notation: what are $b,m$? Integers, elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\star$, or elements of $\mathbb{Z}_m^\star$? You're using them like they're integers, but you wrote $b\in \mathbb{Z}_m^\star$, and at another point $b\in\mathbb{Z}_n^\star$.

Comment: And where is the induction?

Comment: In the fact that he supposed that the quotient n/m is a prime. Then for an arbitrary n/m, you can compose the various surjective maps of jumping-one-prime-per-time

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I had trouble with formatting in the comments.

Evidently, the same proof will work for $R/I \to R/J$ where $R$ is a PID.  The more general problem was considered 
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31495/when-does-a-ring-surjection-imply-a-surjection-of-the-group-of-units) and
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/32883).

A nice generalization is that a surjection $f: R \to S$, where the rings are commutative Artinian, maps units onto units.